# Two RelativeLayouts, with the same height

Tags: android, xml, height, android-relativelayout

I have two `RelativeLayout`s (one next to each other).
A white `RelativeLayout` and a red one.

As the amount of the text in the white side increases, I want the the red side to grow.

Comment: You need to post the xml of what you have and explain the exact problem. Right now, it's pretty unclear what *exactly* you expect to happen and what *is actually* happening. Images in these types of questions are usually helpful, as well.

Comment: I've tried to make your question more clear. If I've inadvertently changed the meaning, feel free to roll back or edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the red RelativeLayout **android:layout_alignBottom** to the id of the white RelativeLayout?

I'm not sure how your text is being input into the white layout but if you are dealing with an EditText inside of the white RelativeLayout then this should make sure that the red side is always the same height as the white as new text is added causing the white side to grow in height.

Something along the lines of this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/white"
        android:background="#FF0000">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/white"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/red"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put the red side first? and then the white side (with the edit text)?

Comment: I changed it around for you so that red side is first and the white side is second.